# CMake package (Cpack) - automatically adding dependencies

Tags: deployment, build, cmake, installation, cpack

I am using the `install` command in cmake to install a target, and while the target it is indeed copied, none of its dependencies are (I am talking about the build-time dependencies, like projects added with `ExternalProject_Add`). How do I automatically include these as well?

Answer (score 0):

CMake does not count "dependencies" when do install. Dependencies are considered only at build time (w/ `target_link_libraries`). So, to include dependencies (whatever they are) into a package/distribution you ought to add `install` calls (some way or another) for them as well. And there is no way to do it "automatically" %)